# Camel - Body becomes empty after logging

Tags: java, apache-camel, esb

Looks like a weird issue or the docs are missing

**Case 1**

```
from("direct:ROUTE1").to("someAPI").to("direct:ROUTE2");
from("direct:ROUTE2").log("${body}");  // BODY is printing
```

**Case 2**

```
from("direct:ROUTE1").to("someAPI").to("direct:ROUTE2").log("${body}");
from("direct:ROUTE2").log("${body}");  // BODY is empty
```

Does adding log clear the exchange body??

Comment: See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Spara and @Claus suggested and to save the hassle on how to enable Stream caching.

Below is the sample code:

> Using Java DSL for Single route

```
from("direct:ROUTER1")
    .streamCaching()
    .to("direct:ROUTER2");
```

> Using Spring DSL for Single route

```
<route streamCache="true">
   <from uri="direct:ROUTER1"/>
   <to uri="direct:ROUTER2"/>
</route>
```

> For global and per route scope using JAVA DSL

```
   context.setStreamCache(true);

      from("direct:ROUTER1")
         .to("direct:ROUTER2");
```

> For global and per route scope using Spring DSL

```
<route streamCache="true">
   <from uri="direct:ROUTER1"/>
   <to uri="direct:ROUTER2"/>
</route>
```

Note link: [Camel Stream Caching](http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html)
[why stream caching](http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html)

Comment: This answer was better than what chatGPT could give me. Humans rule.